# Android : Toolbar Subtitle Gravity Right Not Working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I want to create actionbar subtitle but its gravity should be right. It should end at title end. Please see following image

[image]

My Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ToolbarSubtitleAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Toolbar in Layout File :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Can i achieve this via doing small changes because i had included in many layout file.

Answer (score 0):

**make your toolbar like this so your can custimize as you want**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="title "/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sub title "/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```